# Modify JSON in Form and post back via jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json

I get some JSON data via PHP using this code:

```
$sURL = "https://SOMEURL";
$aOptions = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header' => "Content-type: application/json",
        'method'  => 'POST',
    ),
);

$sContext  = stream_context_create($aOptions);
$sResult = file_get_contents($sURL, false, $sContext);

$aItems = json_decode($sResult, true);

foreach($aItems as $key=>$value)
{
    if ($key == "data")
    {
        foreach ($value as $arritem => $arrcont)
        {
            foreach ($arrcont as $subarritem => $subarrcont)
            {
                if ($subarrcont['ItemId'] == $sItemID)
                {
                    $aItem = $subarrcont;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So in the end I have an array $aItem which contains all the JSON information which looks like this:

```
(
    [ItemId] => consumable_item_1
    [ItemClass] => Consumables
    [CatalogVersion] => 1
    [DisplayName] => Consumable Item 1
    [Description] => Item demonstrating usage-based consumables
    [VirtualCurrencyPrices] => Array
        (
            [VC] => 500
        )

    [Consumable] => Array
        (
            [UsageCount] => 3
        )

)
```

Now, I have a HTML / PHP Form where these data get filled in text boxes and they can modify them.
They also can fill some empty textboxes since this array for example do not have all information that is possible to have (e.g. could have another Array in it or a second ID).

I have this code at the bottom of my page to execute a PHP script when you click a button.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.btn').click(function(){
            var clickBtnValue = $(this).val();
            var ajaxurl = 'ajax.php',
                data =  {'action': clickBtnValue};
            $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {
                // Response div goes here.
                alert("Data saved");
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Now my questions are, how do I modify the existing array with the updated information from the form and how do I pass it over in the $.post in the jQuery Script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from your explination you have filled a HTML-form with your PHP-data. After the user is done with the data (modifined or not) you will have to send thas data back to a PHP script(ajax.php) to handle this, instead of sending the value of only the button as you have done so far you should send the whole form like so:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.btn').click(function(){
            var ajaxurl = 'ajax.php',
                data =  $('form').serialize();
            $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {
                // Response div goes here.
                alert("Data saved");
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Now in your ajax.php you can use the user modified data.
You could also consider making your ajax function fallbackable if javascript is not working like so:

**Javascript**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('form').submit(function (event){
            event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: $(this).attr('action');
                method: $(this).attr('method');
                data: $(this).serialize();
                success: function (response) {
                    // Response div goes here.
                    alert("Data saved");
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<form action="ajax.php" method="post">
   ...
</form>
```